# Install path of Perl6 modules with Panda

Tags: raku

I'm struggling to find the path of Panda installed modules and I haven't found so far.
Moreover, @*INC does not show me anything.

I'm trying to find somewhere in:
/home/toniher/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/install/share/perl6/

Any hint would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure @*INC is no longer a thing, replaced by the concurrency friendly $*REPO chain.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can dump Rakudo's include paths via

```
perl6 -e '.put for $*REPO.repo-chain'
```

Note that the names of installed modules are mangled to allow for installation of different versions of a given module or modules of same name but different authority.

Comment: Thanks! I see that module filenames are a bit "obfuscated", as you say.

Comment: Works with `Rakudo version 2015.12 built on MoarVM version 2015.12 implementing Perl 6.c`. (Didn't work with my installation of Rakudo Star 2015.11)